# Troubleshooting a SQL Server instance that won't start

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration, startup

I've had a problem with one instance of SQL Server 2008 (the free version) not starting automatically. I always have to right click on the icon in the task bar and start it manually. It is set to "Automatic" start mode in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.
I have checked the error log text file and there is nothing that looks likely. I don't see any attempt at automatic startup, just the log of my manual startup.

I then dug into the Event Viewer and I see two warning entries, given around computer boot time:

1. Warning - SQLBrowser - The configuration of the SQL instance UPSWSDBSERVER is not valid.
2. Warning - MSSQL$UPSWSDBSERVER -

   > The description for Event ID ( 19011 ) in Source ( MSSQL$UPSWSDBSERVER
   >   ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary
   >   registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a
   >   remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to
   >   retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The
   >   following information is part of the event: (SpnRegister) : Error
   >   1355.

`UPSWSDBSERVER` is the server instance for UPS WorldShip. This is NOT the instance that I am having trouble with. In fact I never have trouble with it... the UPS software works 100% reliably. The instance I am having trouble with is tied to a program called ShipWorks.

I have run the UPS Diagnostic tool which runs (what appears to be) a thorough check on its database, everything passes. I can **not** see the `UPSWSDVSERVER` instance in the Configuration Manager. Where the heck is it? The configuration manager only lists the ShipWorks instance.

Comment: Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/09/18/sql-browser-service-is-not-running-on-server.aspx